# Stereo "tone-generator" for linux?

Tags: audio, libraries

Is there something like a stereo (separate left-and right-channel) tone-generator for Linux?  Where you can set volume and tone/pitch for each channel, and preferably also set the wave-form (sine, square, sawtooth, ...) and invert one channel (as opposed to the other).

If not, any ideas for a good places to start to make one?  I guess the simplest would be to adapt existing programs like synths...  But if that work poorly, are there any libraries (like SDL?) that can be used as bases for such a program?

Comment: You might be able to get it done with sox.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245897/audio-tone-sine-generator-with-frequency-gauge

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) which is a cross-platform open source audio editor. One of its features is to allow you to generate tones. It's a multi-track audio editor, so you can easily create a stereo tone.

Under the `Generate` menu, you're able to create Sine, Sawtooth, and Square waveform tones of arbitrary frequency, amplitude, and length without the need for recording or needing additional input files.

Comment: But can it generate tones "from nothing"?  And I'm not intending to record and playback anything, just generate two slightly different tones (one for each channel) "for eternity".

Comment: @BaardKopperud Yes, I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 22):

**ffmpeg**

ffmpeg can do it, as usual.

Create a 2 second mono 1000 Hz sinusoidal `out.wav` sound file:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000:d=2" out.wav
```

Stereo instead with `-ac 2`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000:d=2" -ac 2 out.wav
```

The file will be 2x as large, and `ffprobe` will say it has `2 channels` instead of `1 channel`.

Generate 2 seconds of 500 Hz on left and 1000 Hz on right, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551013/how-to-generate-stereo-sine-wave-using-ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex '
sine=f=500[0];
sine=f=1000[1];
[0][1]amerge,atrim=end=2
' out.wav
```

Play the 1000 Hz for 2 seconds without creating a file:

```
ffplay -autoexit -nodisp -f lavfi -i 'sine=f=1000:d=2'
```

Play 1000 Hz forever until you go mad:

```
ffplay -nodisp -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1000"
```

Produce a 2 second mixture/overlay of 500 Hz and 1000 Hz on both channels, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-downmix-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=500[0];
sine=f=1000[1];
[0][1]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2
'
```

Produce 2 seconds of 500 Hz followed by 2 seconds of 1000 Hz:

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=500:d=2[0];
sine=f=1000:d=2[1];
[0][1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1
'
```

2 seconds of 250 Hz + 500 Hz followed by two seconds of 1000 Hz + 2000 Hz:

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit -f lavfi -i '
sine=f=250[0];
sine=f=500[1];
sine=f=1000[2];
sine=f=2000[3];
[0][1]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2[01];
[2][3]amix=inputs=2, atrim=end=2[23];
[01][23]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out];
'
```

Frequency sweep from 0 to 20 kHZ over 10 seconds, main question: https://superuser.com/questions/1156429/how-to-generate-a-time-dependent-frequency-wave/1156468#1156468

```
ffplay -autoexit -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc='sin(2000*t*2*PI*t)':d=10"
```

Documentation:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine
- https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi

The other section sunder [Audio sources](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Audio-Sources) document other useful sound generation algorithms in addition to `sine`, e.g.:

- [`anoisesrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anoisesrc): noises of several colors, e.g. white, pink, brown
- [`aevalsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc) takes arbitrary mathematical expressions, and should therefore be able to produce triangular waveforms (TODO expression)

Bibliography:

- https://superuser.com/questions/724391/how-to-generate-a-sine-wave-with-ffmpeg
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831214/how-to-run-ffplay-as-a-window-less-process/53295994#53295994

Tested on ffmpeg 6.0, Ubuntu 23.10.

**Minimal C audio generation example without extra libraries**

Just for fun: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732699/how-is-audio-represented-with-numbers-in-computers/36510894#36510894

Answer (score 12):

You might look at `speaker-test`, which (on an Arch machine) I find in alsa-utils package.

`speaker-test -c2 -t sine` run from an xterm, gave me a 440 Hz sine wave for about 6 seconds each, alternating left and right speakers.  In the xterm, it gave some information about which speaker it thought it was using.

According to the man page, it can do sine waves of arbitrary frequency and pink noise.

Comment: `speaker-test -c2 -t sine -f 440` will complement your example by giving the frequency parameter.  Thanku.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the frequency parameter apparently has no effect without `-t sine`, since the `-t` option default is pink noise.

Comment: This tool makes 8000Hz at most, in my case.

Answer (score 6):

The [`siggen` program](https://web.archive.org/web/20170225125256/http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/jj/linux/siggen.html) should do the trick.

[image: screenshot of siggen]

It has two channels with independent signals and a phase between them. Each channel can do these signal types:

- sine
- cosine
- square
- triangle
- sawtooth
- pulse
- noise

You can run it in stereo mode like this:

```
siggen -2
```

Note that this relies on `/dev/dsp` which was provided by
[OSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System).
OSS was superseded by [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) and [deprecated around 2006](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8953781/), so you will probably need to install a compatibility library. [On Debian-based distros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436361/sound-card-doesnt-support-format-requested-using-signalgen/436834#436834), install the `alsa-oss` package and run it like this:

```
aoss siggen -2
```

You can also try it with the PulseAudio OSS Wrapper which is provided with the `pulseaudio-utils` package:

```
padsp siggen -2
```

Comment: I get: [siggen] Input/output error : /dev/dsp

Comment: Hm. Does the PulseAudio OSS wrapper help at all?

Comment: Yep. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

The [saugns](https://sau.frama.io/) program can also do it. (It is a command-line audio generator supporting [a language](https://sau.frama.io/language.html) including more types of audio generation, including centrally FM/PM and AM/RM modulation techniques.)

To generate two stereo-separated 100 Hz waves, one a sine and one a triangle, and one with inverted amplitude, the following script can be pasted into a file and ran through the program (as in `./saugns filename`):

```
Wsin f100 a0.5 t2 cL
Wtri f100 a(-0.5) t2 cR
```

This is also short enough that it can instead simply be ran as a one-liner directly:

```
./saugns -e "Wsin f100 a0.5 t2 cL Wtri f100 a(-0.5) t2 cR"
```

The `t`s specify time, in seconds.

The `c`s are for changing the channel mixing (L = hard left, R = hard right) from the default (C = center). Any numbers from "(-1.0)" to "1.0" can also be used for [such values](https://sau.frama.io/language.html#channels).

*Old edit:* I'm indeed the developer of the program.

Also, an alternative way of flipping the amplitude (for some wave types, e.g. `sin` but not `saw`), is to set the phase using a lowercase `p`. Adding `p0.5` sets phase to 50% of the wave cycle (negative half). Further, as there's no named cosine type, `p0.25` is the way to turn sine into cosine (or `p0.75` for negative cosine).

Comment: Hi Joel. Welcome to [unix.se]. I've upvoted your answer as it's a great first post. I thought I'd mention that if you're a maintainer or developer of a project, it's standard practice to disclose this information. While not really an issue for GPL software, it's worth being aware of https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion For useful Free/Libre software, I'd imagine that you'd be *more* likely to get upvoted on this site if users know you're one of the developers behind the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily synthesize tones with SoX. There were some stumbling blocks but I was eventually able to figure it out.

I had trouble interfacing SoX with PulseAudio so I just pipe `sox` raw data into `paplay`.

The pipeline is tedious so I created a script:

```
$ cat sox-paplay
#!/bin/bash
: ${HZ:=44100}
: ${NCHAN:=6}
: ${SINK:=mysink}
sox -c $NCHAN -n -t raw -r $HZ -L -b 16 - "$@" | paplay --no-remix --no-remap --raw -v -p --rate $HZ -d $SINK --channels $NCHAN
```

e.g.

```
sox-paplay synth sine 1000 gain -5 remix -m 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

The `remix` effect is just used to send the result to a specific channel. It is much more powerful but we only use the basic functionality here. In this example we have a six-channel device and we're sending a tone to the third channel.

I originally created an ALSA device wrapping the PulseAudio device, but then I found that it is impossible to control the channel mapping using ALSA, and so random channels were getting mixed together according to how my custom channel-map differed from the ALSA default. This is why I have `--no-remix --no-remap` in `paplay` above; I just want the raw channel ordering for the sox command.

I kind of wish that audio stuff on Linux had better documentation and error reporting.

You may be interested in an answer I posted recently showing how to [set the PulseAudio Equalizer from the command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508498/118662).

Answer (score 1):

```
play -n synth sine 1000 gain -5 remix -m 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It requires `sox` installed

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Gnaural](http://gnaural.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It would be best to [edit] this answer to include more information about how this program provides the features being asked about - similar to the other answers previously posted.