# Audio tone/sine generator with frequency gauge

Tags: audio

I want to flatten frequency response of my headphones with EQ (to dramatically increase sound quality with only a bit of time), but I need tone generator for that with live manually selectable frequency gauge, so I can dynamically move it and locate peaks. EQing by playing samples of different tones is much more cumbersome and less accurate.

I need something like this: http://www.tucows.com/preview/502787/SineGen I'd love to not have to use wine.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82112/stereo-tone-generator-for-linux

Comment: Finally I used one of "Online Tone Generator" results from Google. These don't have any non-GUI interface, but you can use mouse to freely change frequency with any speed you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a program in the standard repos called
[`siggen`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170225125256/http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/jj/linux/siggen.html)
that can do this.

[image: screenshot of siggen]

It has a `curses` interface,
and you can increment or decrement the frequency with the arrow keys.

Since `/dev/dsp` is deprecated in most modern Linux distros, you will probably need to install a compatibility library. [On Debian-based distros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436361/sound-card-doesnt-support-format-requested-using-signalgen/436834#436834), install the `alsa-oss` package and run it like this:

```
$ aoss siggen
```

or with the PulseAudio OSS Wrapper like so:

```
$ padsp siggen
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `speaker-test` for that.

```
speaker-test -c1 -t sine -f 440
```

produces a sine wave of 440 Hz out of my left front speaker. I used a tuning app on my Android phone to verify the frequencies that `speaker-test` produces. The android app measured the specified tone to within 0.1 Hz.

I used an oscilloscope android app to see the sound waveform, and it showed a decent sine wave. The right front speaker of my laptop has a worse sine wave than the left front.

Comment: Thank you, but I need something to sweep smoothly through frequencies so I can hear if there's a dip or peak, how wide etc. Anyway nice tip about oscilloscope, I'll use this on my speakers just for science ;]